# gravatar_for no method error Hartl rails chapter 7

Tags: ruby, erb, nomethoderror, gravatar, ruby-on-rails-5

Everything was working fine till I tried defining gravatar_for and calling it.  `user.email.downcase` is nil class.  Below is what I am working with.  Let me know if you need any other information.

I see when running localhost at url `http://localhost:3000/users/1`
`NoMethodError in Users#show`

```
`Showing /Users/nathandewaele/Desktop/workspce/static_pages/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass`
```

extracted source around line 5
`gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)`

```
`Rails.root: /Users/nathandewaele/Desktop/workspce/static_pages

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:in `gravatar_for'
app/views/users/show.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___4114710587947303689_70365956197180'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None`
```

## app/helpers/users_helper.rb

````
```rb

module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```
````

## app/controllers/users_controller.rb

````
```ruby

class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
        @user = User.new
  end
end
```
````

## app/db/schema.rb

````
```ruby

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171108202327) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```
````

## app/controllers/config/routes.rb

````
```ruby

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # get '/new', to: 'users#new'
    get '/show', to: 'users#show'
    get  '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
    get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
    get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
    get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'

    resources :users
end
```
````

## app/views/users/show.html.erb

````
```erb

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```
````

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGqQm.png)

Comment: Please check the user object in `gravatar_for` method seems like email is not present that's why downcase is throwing the error.

Comment: When `user.email.downcase` raises an `undefined method `downcase for nil` error than `user.email` obviously returns `nil`. Your user in the database doesn't have an email. Fix that and the error will be gone.

Comment: spickermann - you are right!  but I just went to instantiate a new user and the email comes up as nil.
`=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Naters", email: nil, created_at: "2017-11-17 22:58:34", updated_at: "2017-11-17 22:58:34", password_digest: "$2a$10$oRTXEUFarNBBV7ziJWG7/uIb20wiYR8ghB8dHRrtVAg...">, #<User id: 2, name: "Naters", email: nil, created_at: "2017-11-18 16:27:45", updated_at: "2017-11-18 16:27:45", password_digest: "$2a$10$BwF.FJmluyHiTeME96zpnekI6pWngXdYnUq8iihpspc...">]>`

Comment: Why does my email come in as nil when I am putting it in?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, resolved when I updated /app/helpers/users_helper with the code:

```
  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
```

(as shown in Listing 7.9)

Comment: This was too helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, which was hard to trace! As mentioned above, an email was not being sent to the database. My problem appeared to resolve itself after I changed code in my model/users.rb file that I was confusing myself with:
`before_save { self.email = email.downcase }`.

Before I had used `before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }`. Validation is located in Chapter 6 of the Rails Tutorial. Somehow I was confusing `email.downcase`! with `self.email = email.downcase`.

This still leaves the mystery of why an account was created without an email, instead of an error preventing me from proceeding...